# how to test for Internet Explorer user agent using node js

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, user-agent

How can I test for Internet explorer (Ie 11 and below) and microsoft edge using Node js?

I tried

```
navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE/i)
```

but that only covers IE < 11

I tried

```
!navigator.userAgent.match('MSIE') && !navigator.userAgent.match('Trident') && !navigator.userAgent.match('Edge')
```

My problem: I am using CSS filters to filter an image. CSS filters is not supported in Internet Explorer or Edge. How can I check that CSS filters are enabled using javascript or check that the user is not using IE or Edge?

Comment: What does this have to do with node.js?   `navigator.userAgent` is a browser property, not anything available in node.js.  And, since user agent sniffing is generally considered a bad idea and should be replaced with feature detection, I'd suggest you post what your real problem is and perhaps folks can help you solve it with user agent detection.

Comment: In my previous comment, I meant solve it WITHOUT user agent detection.

Comment: So what is your goal? Why are you not doing the detection on the client?

Comment: Friends don't let other friends attempt user-agent detection of IE.  It's an imperfect art at best and one that [changes frequently](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869301(v=vs.85).aspx).    

In this case, there's not much you can do, except perhaps put a tasteful note on the page.  IE doesn't support [CSS filter effects](http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20filter%20effects) and it unlikely to in the future.  There is a polyfill that works for [older versions of IE](https://github.com/Schepp/CSS-Filters-Polyfill).